# FIR output verification online without MATLAB

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I need to test my FIR, IIR and FFT code. I have sample code, I need to know the ouput to see if my code really works. I don't have access to MATLAB. Please suggest any method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific test platform (C, Java, etc) in mind, [Gnu Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is a great free alternative to MATLAB.